# Regexp to extract protocol, domain and first path after domain name and its inverse

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I'm tasked to parse a couple thousand logfiles and identify usage patterns so that we can redesign our infrastructure. 
However due to RGPD compliance, I must strip all personal information, identities, timestamps and so on. In the end this info will also be relayed to all stakeholders in percentage pie charts.
Hence, lets say our log files hold the info bellow:

```
userid=u015453; timestamp=2015/02/04 07:22:055 GET: http://www.example.com/users/user/u001
userid=u124244; timestamp=2018/05/22 10:22:112 GET: http://www.example.com/users/user/u002
userid=carldoe; timestamp=2019/06/12 11:36:441 GET: http://www.example.com/users/user/u003
userid=johndoe; timestamp=2019/05/04 19:22:253 GET: https://www.example.com/blog/2019/01/01/i-know-what-you-did-last-winter/?id=123232455&referrer=...
userid=sophia_p; timestamp=2019/05/04 05:22:144 GET: https://www.example.com/blog/2019/07/22/how-to-keep-hidrated-this-summer/
userid=alanWalker; timestamp=2018/07/04 23:22:557 GET: https://www.example.com/factcheck/turbocompressors
userid=justinTrudeau; timestamp=2017/07/09 19:33:798 GET: https://www.example.com/specifications/seatbelts?id=1232423
userid=justinTrudeau; timestamp=2017/07/09 19:33:798 GET: https://www.example.com/specifications/airbag?id=56551666&brand=ford&...
userid=FrankSinatra; timestamp=2019/04/25 12:22:778 GET: https://www.example.com/specifications/seatbelt?id=1232423&referer=google.de&appversion=2.3.3&.....
userid=null; timestamp=2019/02/28 23:57:662 GET: https://www.example.com/specifications/seatbelts?id=1232423&referer=google.de&appversion=2.3.3&.....
```

So, based in the example above I want to devise a REGEXP that **must discard everything but protocol, domain and section**, so i should end up with this:

```
http://www.example.com/users/
http://www.example.com/users/
http://www.example.com/users/
https://www.example.com/blog/
https://www.example.com/blog/
https://www.example.com/factcheck/
https://www.example.com/specifications/
https://www.example.com/specifications/
https://www.example.com/specifications/
https://www.example.com/specifications/
```

This info will be parsed in a python script where I’ll construct a python dictionary with the intended section as the key and the corresponding value will hold the number of matches found. 
In the end I'll know that for domain *www.example.com* we got 3 User views, 2 Blog visits, 1 Fact-check and that 4 people were interested in our Specification's section

I’ve already tried this:

```
https?:\/\/[A-Za-z]{2,5}\.?.*\.[a-z]{2,3}\.*\/.*\/+
```

However this REGEXP is too greedy and will match way more than the second slash, hence almost useless as it stands right now.
Is there a way to stop this regexp at most at the second slash just after TLD and ignore all the rest? 
Note that that second slash might not exist at all, like when a user has just landed on main page.
It is also possible to ***invert this same REGEXP*** so that I can ***capture everything outside the matching expression***?

Other thoughts:
Domain prefixes may or may not exist at all. 
IE: I need to either find https://example.com as well https://www.example.com ,  https://api.example.com, as well as country TLD domains, like https://example.de, http://www.example.pl, https://api.example.fr and so on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(.*)(https?:\/\/([a-zA-Z]+\.)?example\.[a-zA-Z]+\/[^\/\r\n]+\/?)(.*)
```

So if you apply this regex to:

```
userid=u015453; timestamp=2015/02/04 07:22:055 GET: http://www.example.com/users/user/u001
```

then the following will be available in the capture groups:

- `\1` = `userid=u015453; timestamp=2015/02/04 07:22:055 GET:`
- `\2` = `http://www.example.com/users/`
- `\3` = `user/u001`

https://regex101.com/r/aDwoLv/4

Comment: This regexp does not work as it's also greedy, just like mine.
For instance in this link: "https://www.example.com/blog/2019/01/01/i-know-what-you-did-last-winter/?id=123232455&referrer=" it will capture this: "https://www.example.com/blog/2019/01/01/i-know-what-you-did-last-winter/"

Comment: Why do you say that? It works on regex101. My only guess is that regex101 is using a newer version of Python

Comment: Actually @MonkeyZeus works as intended in python, but not in a text editor like Notepad++ (Boost engine).
Hence as this is a python project, I'm gonna accept your answer.
Still, if someone knows a way to negate this regexp, that would be really appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: @mjoao I'll add some instruction for NP++

Comment: @mjoao I also updated the Python example to perform substitution. You can check the CodeGenerator on the regex101 page to see how to achieve the desired results.

Comment: Thank you@MonkeyZeus.


When I wrote "negate" I meant:
Is there a way to capture the remainder of the main regexp expression?
For instance in this line:
"userid=alanWalker; timestamp=2018/07/04 23:22:557 GET: https://www.example.com/factcheck/turbocompressors"

is it possible to capture everything that is not captured in the first regexp like so: 

"userid=alanWalker; timestamp=2018/07/04 23:22:557 GET: turbocompressors"
Once again thank you.

Comment: @mjoao That's what the `.*` does at the beginning and end. Just wrap it in a capture group and access it via `\2` or whatever position it happens to be.

Comment: @mjoao Sorry, I didn't read your entire post until just now because it was too chatty so hopefully my latest edit clears things up